# Assertion failure at random with Boost.Regex 1.53 and gcc 4.8.1 on CentOS 6.4

Tags: c++, regex, boost, c++11, shared-ptr

Here is the code I'm working with to test regular expressions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
//#include <regex>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto isMatch = [](const std::string& text, const std::string& pattern)->bool
    {
        return boost::regex_search(text,
            boost::regex(pattern, boost::regex::icase | boost::regex::nosubs)
        );
    };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isMatch("Hello, world!",
        R"(((\%3D)|(=))[^\n]*((\%27)|(\')|(\-\-)|(\%3B)|(;)))") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine, but when I run it, *sometimes* I get an assertion failure on what I can safely assume is a null shared_ptr that isn't supposed to be null. It happens seemingly at random as demonstrated here:

```
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
false
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
regextest: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
false
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
regextest: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
regextest: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
regextest: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
regextest: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
regextest: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
false
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
false
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
regextest: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
false
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
false
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
regextest: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
false
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
regextest: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
regextest: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char> >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$ ./regextest
false
[jacktrueborn@inpost regextest]$
```

And this is how I installed boost:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr
sudo ./b2 install
```

I know this has been a problem in the past with this library and I haven't been able to find a satisfactory work-around; I'm wondering if one has surfaced and I just haven't seen it. However, I'm not sure if I'm even having the same problem given the flaky nature of the error. `std::regex` simply throws `std::regex_error`s while running so I can't use that.

(I'm aware that isMatch doesn't need to be a lambda or even a real function in this instance, but in my non-contrived code, there is a reason for doing it this way.)

Comment: Do you have different versions of boost installed? That seems to be the problem, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545689/boost-regex-runtime-error) which is the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried using `valgrind`?  Don't bother using `std::regex`, [it's not implemented in libstdc++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/981959)

Comment: @JesseGood: +1. That was the issue, indeed, but the question you posted didn't give me a fix. Fortunately, it was a fairly easy (if somewhat scary) fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, as pointed out, two different versions of Boost being installed. However, **the steps for how to fix the problem** were *not* addressed in the suggested question. Here is what I had to do:

1. Remove the system packaged Boost library (I don't know if this step was actually required because of the following two steps I had to perform):

   `sudo yum remove boost-devel`
2. Remove all the leftover Boost libs:

   `sudo find /usr -name 'libboost_*' -delete`
3. Remove all the leftover Boost includes including the Boost folder itself:

   `sudo rm -rf /usr/include/boost`
4. Reinstall Boost 1.53 (from above):

   `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr`

   `sudo ./b2 install`

In my case, I also had to update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to `/usr/lib` as the variable didn't even exist before.

At any rate, the code works now. Every time. No runtime errors at all.